# Executing Bash files on Cygwin error

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

In relatively new at bash scripting and when running my script files on the cygwin shell I have some errors that make me think there's something about cygwin I'm missing. I've read several tutorials and copied a script from one of them (trying to understand whats wrong with mine) that is supposed to be OK but i get the following error (same one than my script):

```
': no es un identificador válido

./pruebas.sh: línea 17: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `fi'

./pruebas.sh: línea 17: `fi'
```

Translated into English I think errors should be like:

```
': is not a valid identifier

./pruebas.sh: line 17: sintax error near unexpected element `fi'

./pruebas.sh: line 17: `fi'
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Test IF-ELSE

echo ' Adivina el valor numerico de la variable'
read A
if [ $A = 1 ];
then
echo 'Has acertado'
exit 0
else
if [ $A = 2 ];
then
echo 'Estuviste cerca'
fi
else
echo 'Erraste'
fi
```

Any ideas of what's going wrong? Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: A work mate can execute my script on windows by double clicking without problems. For this reason I guess it must be something wrong with cygwin or the configuration of my pc

Comment: Your syntax is invalid, so I'd be very surprised if double clicking it was working at all!

Comment: I get `syntax error at line 14: 'else' unexpected` which is what I would have expected. Maybe you need to `dos2unix myScript.sh` in case you've created file with Windows line-endings? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter my initial suspicion was line endings too but then I realised that the syntax was invalid. I guess it's possible that both things could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of an `if` is like this:

```
if condition_1; then 
    action_1
elif condition_2; then
    action_2
else
    action_3
fi
```

With that in mind, I would change your code to this:

```
echo ' Adivina el valor numerico de la variable'
read a
if [ "$a" = 1 ]; then
    echo 'Has acertado'
    exit 0
elif [ "$a" = 2 ]; then
    echo 'Estuviste cerca'
else
    echo 'Erraste'
fi
```

Comment: Changed the code as you suggested but still the same error (just changes line 17 for line 16)

Comment: With the last update i get this error: ': no es un identificador válido ;
./pruebas.sh: línea 9: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `elif';
'/pruebas.sh: línea 9: `elif [ "$a" = 2 ]; then

Comment: Fix your line endings!

Comment: Finally mi real problem was windows line endings. Thanks for your advices :)